How to achieve Column mapping just like in ADF in Databricks

As you can see , this is the general column mapping with dtypes in a copy activity in ADF where we can change the dtypes, col names etc from Source to Destination.
If I want the same setup in databricks like I need to map the Id column with CustomerID, How can achieve this because i just know how to read the table and write the table from and to SQL servers if the schema matches. But here i need a custom mapping so that all the cols will be populated correctly from Source Schema to Destination Schema.
I know I can rename the cols just as Target before writing to Target.Thats kinda very manual way and definitely need a more efficient and automated way ,kinda generic function so that i can use the function for all other tables too.
And Both Source and Target tables are created on some for example dev catelog ,so these are the warehouse Sql server tables.

Can you provide the details of source table and destination table are those in sql db or dataframe in databricks?

As mentioned in the picture, 3 cols ---> 3 Cols. Populate data of your choice thats not important.

When you are looking for a GUI solution in Databricks then you will not find something similar to ADF. You need to provide spark code. The renaming in ADF is also not done automatically. Anyone needs to give the information what the target column should be like otherwise the destination name is called like the input.
What I do is having a TableMapping class that iterates over its ColumnMapping instances and calls the apply_column_renaming_and_casting function. But this method picks up only the defined columns. And the columns need to be cast save. If you want a projection of all columns just write some dummy code to recognize the input-columns and add it to the columns attribute.
Something similar to the following code should be happen in the background of ADF.
your_df = load_your_dataframe_by_whatever
df_new = table_mapper.apply_column_renaming_and_casting(your_df)


table_mapper = TableMapping(
    name="any name",
    columns=[
        ColumnMapping(
            target=Column(
                name="CustomerId", dtype=IntegerType(), nullable=True
            ),
            source=Column(
                name="Id", dtype=StringType(), nullable=True
            )
        ),
        ColumnMapping(
            target=Column(name="LastName", dtype=StringType(), nullable=True),
            source=Column(name="Name", dtype=StringType(), nullable=True),
        ),
    ]
)


@dataclass
class TableMapping:
    """
    Definition of one spark table [DataFrame] to another.
    Can be used to select and rename columns, as well as for casting dtypes.
    """

    name: str
    """the name of the target table"""
    columns: List["ColumnMapping"]
    """The columns of the table (target and source)"""

    def apply_column_renaming_and_casting(self, df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
        """
        A function to rename and cast a table to the target schema.
        :param df:
        :return:
        """
        for column in self.columns:
            if column.source and (column.source.name != column.target.name):
                df = df.withColumnRenamed(column.source.name, column.target.name)
            if column.source and (column.source.dtype != column.target.dtype):
                df = df.withColumn(
                    column.target.name,
                    f.col(column.target.name).cast(column.target.dtype),
                )

        return df


@dataclass
class ColumnMapping:
    """
    Definition of a single column mapping (source to target column).
    """

    target: "Column" = None
    """This is the target (output) column"""
    source: "Column" = None
    "This is the source (input) column. When omitted, the target column will be empty."

@dataclass
class Column:
    """
    Column definition, consisting of name and dtype
    """

    name: str
    """Name of the column"""
    dtype: DataType
    """Dtype of the column"""
    nullable: bool
    """Nullable property of the column"""


Hey Samuel .Can I get a simpler function just for mapping eliminating all the OOPs concepsts.Because here we do only pyspark.

Pyspark runs with Python. So the above OOP method should be the best and cleanest way to achieve waht you want to do. Also you need somewhere to mention the columns that should get casted and renamed.  As I mentioned the GUI that you are using in ADF has almost the same logic behind the scenes. You can implement this code in any databricks notebook or wheel and run it. You can simply add more table_mapper instances per you need.

You can follow the procedure below to map the columns and copy the data as follows:
Here is my sample source dataframe:



id
name
lastmodified




1
AA
2024-04-10


2
BB
2024-04-11


3
CC
2024-04-12



And sample target dataframe:



CustomerId
lastname
modified_date










You can use the code below to map the columns and copy the data:
target_df = source_df \
    .withColumn("CustomerId", source_df["id"]) \
    .withColumn("lastname", source_df["name"]) \
    .withColumn("modified_date", source_df["lastmodified"]) \
    .drop("id", "name", "lastmodified")
 

Or:
target_df = source_df.select(
    source_df["id"].alias("CustomerId"),
    source_df["name"].alias("lastname"),
    source_df["lastmodified"].alias("modified_date")
)

After the code execution above, the target_df is as follows:



CustomerId
lastname
modified_date




1
AA
2024-04-10


2
BB
2024-04-11


3
CC
2024-04-12




You misunderstood. I have 2 tables existing , i should not rename any of the table names as that is not allowed in real project. Consider a copy activity in ADF,it just imports the schema and insert the data to destination. Here your creating a new dataframe and renmaing the cols. Remenber  2 tables are existing on Prod and you cant just rename it and put into a dataframe and write that dataframe.Thats a very Manual way, I want like a custom mapping func or somethimg which auto maps the columns just like a copy activity does.

Just want a automated way in short

When i say tables ,they are delta tables .All tables are delta in Databricks

can you check this once?

No. Thats not related.The doc says just how we can perform Alter for renaming or drpping statements to get executed. I need a customised mapping function ,and i definitely know its on the internet,i have searched it a lot.

If you understand copy activity mapping then you can understand what i actially need

It will not* be on the internet

@AzSuryaTeja There is no such thing in databricks which does auto mapping the column names and data types. All you have to do is renaming the columns with custom function as samuel provided. he also done the same thing as Bhavani difference is he given generic class and function.

Yeah . Ok if its not possiboe ,i will go with manual renaming functions.
